# simulating text selection with spans, bottle neck

Tags: jquery, dom

I have text.

Words are wrapped in spans(span IDs are 1,2,3...N):

`<span id="79" class="p">თაობის<div class="p" style="width: 9px; left: -9px; "></div></span>
<span id="80" class="p">განადგურების<div class="p" style="width: 10px; left: -10px; "></div></span>`

I'm simulating text selection by:

I need to simulate text selection by changing span's background colours and filling gap between spans with background filled divs.

When span count is large enough, in Internet Explorer, javascript code which runs through "selected text spans" and calculates gap space between putting there divs(with background color) takes way to much time(Internet Explorer hangs up for up to 30 second in case when total amount of spans is 500).

Comment: There is no way judge the bottleneck in your code unless you put it here.

Comment: html invalidity is not the issue, as we don't need search engines to browse it. But if you think it might be the reason of bottle neck can you suggest anything?

Comment: Are you trying to highlight text on a page? If so, have you taken a look at some of the [jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)s for that?

Answer (score -1):

i dont really understand what do you mean by "simulating text selection"

you could look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/fullpipe/DpP7w/embedded/result/

if you suggest your code, it will be much easy to help you

a lot of time is spending for text generation

Comment: yes I'm doing same thing as shown on the page you gave me link of. My problem is I'm trying to fill the gap between words with additional divs, that's the place where performance problems begin. As I understand it's way to much for IE to add 10 and more divs in some parent div with hundreds of span wrapped words. Anyway thanks, as I understand the only solution is to split text in small chunks, only visible.

Comment: its better to insert divs in text on server side, i think. And this `to much for IE to add 10 and more divs in some parent div`
is not a problem. May be you got some slow loops in you script